# Internal Server Error while adding user to MS Teams

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, azure-rest-api

My requirement is to add a user to MS Teams via Rest API. So I am using endpoint and parameters:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/********/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

```
Body:
'@odata.type':'#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember'
'roles':'[]'
'user@odata.bind':'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('*************')
```

This threw me "InternalServerError". I have no idea why I am getting this error. The complete error looks like:

```
"code": "InternalServerError"
"message": "Failed to execute request."
```

Did anyone face the same scenario I am totally confused. How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I was able to add user to MS Teams like below:***

I granted **`TeamMember.ReadWriteNonOwnerRole.All`** permission to the Application like below:

[image]

***I generated access token via Postman with `Client_Credential` Flow by using parameters like below:***

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id=client_id
&client_secret=client_secret
&grant_type=client_credentials
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

**To add user to MS Teams, please use the below endpoint:**

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/ID/members

'@odata.type':'#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember'
'roles':'[]'
'user@odata.bind':'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('ID')
```

**Response:**

[image]